# jquery .on container element attached to multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, onclick, addeventlistener, propagation

I am using `.on()` to attach click events to multiple elements that appear on the page dynamically. The problem I have is that when I add `.on` to a container on the page and want to attach click events to multiple elements in the container, the latter overwrites the previous.

```
<div id="container">
   <!-- elements here appear dynamically -->
   <div id="id1"></div>
   <div id="id1"></div>
</div>

 <script>
   $('#container').on("click", "#id1", function(){});
   $('#container').on("click", "#id2", function(){});
 </script>
```

In the above example only the click event for id2 works.

Is there a way around this?

Thank you, 
Ev.

Comment: strange you have `id1` and it doesnt work and you dont have `id2` in dom but it works

Comment: In your comments you mentioned that its a typo, you should edit your question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/aRBY4/2/ **little improvement here** http://jsfiddle.net/aRBY4/5/

Yes your `id` is wrong. `:)`

YOu are using same id i.e. `id1` for both elements.

Hope this helps,

**code**

**bit improved code**

```
$('#container').on("click", "#id1, #id2", function() {
    alert($(this).prop('id')) // you can use --> attr('id')
});​
```

**or**

```
 $('#container').on("click", "#id1, #id2", function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id')) 
    });​
```

**or**

```
 $('#container').on("click", "#id1", function(){alert('d1')});
   $('#container').on("click", "#id2", function(){alert('d2')});​
```

Comment: just a small suggestion, `id` is not a property. It should be `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: @Jashwant `:)` done **But** read this bruv - interesting read -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr `:))`

Comment: ha ha...I am feeling low now ( I am dumb ). Never knew that. jQuery docs doesnt mention that. I was thinking that they introduced `prop` just for semantics. Many thanks for the link.

Comment: @Jashwant `:)` no worries bruv, have a nice one! oh and how did your `checkbox` question going? `:))`

Comment: @Tats_innit ids are different sorry for the confusion i miss-typed it here

Comment: @evkorres `:)` no probs in any case you can see the working demo in my post `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit, its still unanswered. thinking to add bounty

Comment: @Jashwant lol okies or we should chat one day may be around weekend, I will see if I will get time, its bit late at my end so will bail out soon. `:)` but will defo take a look into your question again and explain it in more detail. `;)`

Comment: yes it works, but still have the same issue in my actual implementation. I guess it is not a .on issue then will have to look elsewhere. Thank you all. @Jashwant nice read :)

Comment: @evkorres Glad it helped! `:)` +1 to you anyways, and by the way read if from my share, but yes @Jashwant good read indeed `:P`

Answer (score 2):

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/amol9supe/w18ktftb/3/

```
<div id="container">
   //Elements here appear dynamically
   <div id="id1" class="common-id">hulk</div>
   <div id="id2" class="common-id">rambo</div>
</div>

 <!-- Script Here -->
 $('#container').on("click", ".common-id", function() {
    alert(this.id)
 });
```